# Deny access to multiple domains in same directory

Tags: nginx, restriction

I have alot of domain names. configured as virtual hosts in nginx. They all have same document root. I want to restrict access to huge amount of different ip. Is there any way to do it in highest level then virtual hosts configuration? For example in main http{} block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use  [ngx_http_geo_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) to block certain IPs from accessing your virtual hosts. This module helps you create variables with values based on client IP address. You can define the IPs at http level. Here is an example.

```
http {

    geo $spamers {
          # --allow all --
          default no;
          #-- block these bad ips --
          192.0.171.118 spam; 
          192.0.179.119 spam;
          192.0.179.120 spam; 
          192.128.168.0/20 spam; 
    }
```

You can add as many IPs you want and then in the location blocks of the servers that you want to restrict these IPs you can add a check

```
location ~* /mysite/www/ {
    if ( $spamers = spam ) {
       # -- Return a forbidden message 
       return 403;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. It require the same job as i did. I added all bad ips in file, in simple deny directives and then include this file in location blocks in every virtual host configurations. I was curious if it's possible to do it without touching virtual host configurations.

Comment: You have to add these rules in all server blocks ( you dont have to write in each location block). The default behavior of nginx is that when a request comes it matches requests header field "Host" with your defined virtual servers. So the request will directly go that server block.